# FFMPEG: Error Making A Video Clip: Invalid duration specification for t:

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm on Linux Mint 19.  I'm trying to extract a video clip from an mkv file.

I found an old sample command in some notes I had, but for mpegs.   I changed the relevant strings and tried running this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -ss 00:12:38.000 -t 00:02:71 output.mkv
```

I got this error message :

```
Invalid duration specification for t: 00:02:71
```

I wanted to start the clip at 12:38 in the video and I wanted the clip to be 2:71 long.

The full output is below.  Thanks for any clues

```
Mint19Cinnamon3.8.9> ffmpeg -i input.mkv -ss 00:12:38.000 -t 00:02:71 output.mkv
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.9 + libmatroska v1.5.2
    creation_time   : 2019-11-15T05:11:58.000000Z
  Duration: 00:49:56.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4331 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 3689288
      DURATION-eng    : 00:49:56.577000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 71846
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1381904488
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v38.0.0 ('The Silent Type') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-11-15 05:11:58
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: eac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 640 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 640000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:49:56.608000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 93644
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 239728640
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v38.0.0 ('The Silent Type') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-11-15 05:11:58
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : English
      BPS-eng         : 54
      DURATION-eng    : 00:47:28.011000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 701
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 19492
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v38.0.0 ('The Silent Type') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-11-15 05:11:58
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Invalid duration specification for t: 00:02:71
Mint19Cinnamon3.8.9>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-t 00:02:71` means 2 minutes and 71 seconds, so should be written as `-t 00:03:11`. If you wanted it to be 2 seconds and 710 milliseconds long, use `-t 00:02.71`